# R: Can I create variables Q1 = mydata$Q1, Q2 = mydata$Q2 automatically from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Supposed I have a dataframe from `read.csv`

`mydata = read.csv(XXX)`

```
Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  ......  Q100
a   e   i   m   ......   w
b   f   j   n   ......   x
c   g   k   o   ......   y
d   h   l   p   ......   z
```

Can I create all variables `Q1 = mydata$Q1`, `Q2 = mydata$Q2`, ..., `Q100 = mydata$Q100` without manually typing all the column names = `mydata$column_names`?

Comment: The fact that you want to rip a `data.frame apart`, plus you using `=` instead of `->` makes me think you're transferring from STATA or a comparable piece of software. @vincentmajor's answer would work and make R behave like STATA a bit. But as has already been pointed it's not advised. Is there a particular reason why you feel you need to do this?

Comment: I am trying to write a VBA and link it with R. I can actually write a loop in VBA to generate the script of Q1 = mydata$Q1, Q2 = mydata$Q2, ..., Q100 = mydata$Q100. What is the problems with scoping? @MattBannert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `attach(mydata)` which adds the column names of `mydata` to the environment for use as `Q1` etc.

Comment: You can do this; however it is not advised. Leads to problems with scoping. @bbbbbliu; what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to write a VBA and link it with R. I can actually write a loop in VBA to generate the script of Q1 = mydata$Q1, Q2 = mydata$Q2, ..., Q100 = mydata$Q100. What is the problems with scoping? @Heroka

Answer (score 0):

You could use the eval(parse=...) trick :) just substitute mydata with your mydata and it will work as a charm. Good luck!

```
mydata <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2), y=c(3, 4), z=c(5, 6))

nn <- colnames(mydata)

for(n in nn){

   eval(parse(text=paste0(n,  "<- mydata$", n)))

}
```